# A java practice problem

Tags: java, logic

I came across this problem in javabat(http://www.javabat.com/prob/p183562):

> We want to make a row of bricks that
>   is goal inches long. We have a number
>   of small bricks (1 inch each) and big
>   bricks (5 inches each). Return true if
>   it is possible to make the goal by
>   choosing from the given bricks. This
>   is a little harder than it looks and
>   can be done without any loops.
>
> makeBricks(3, 1, 8) → true
>   makeBricks(3, 1, 9) → false
>   makeBricks(3, 2, 10) → true

I came up with this solution:

```
public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
    if (goal > small + big * 5)
        return false;
    else if (goal % 5 == 0) 
        return goal / 5 <= big;
    else
        return goal % 5 <= small;
}
```

This passed the test. But I found a counter-example myself: makeBricks(10, 0, 10) -> true. My logic will return false. How should I fix my logic? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This is of course ... one of the practice problems on a Java and Python learning website ... codingbat.com

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you can just remove your second test. I would try this:

```
public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
    if (goal > small + big * 5)
        return false;
    else
        return goal % 5 <= small;
}
```

The first test just checks how long the row would be if we just put *all* the bricks in a row. If that's not as long as the goal, then we know that it's impossible.

Next, we calculate the minimum number of small bricks: `goal % 5`. For example, if the goal is 8 and we have 1000 large bricks, how many small bricks do we need? `8 % 5` is 3, so we need 3 small bricks at the end of the row.

If we have enough small bricks, and the total length of all the bricks is enough, then we can meet the goal.

Comment: why goal%5 <= small
please explain

Comment: I added an explanation, @Man.

Answer (score 11):

Your logic is incorrect. This should do it:

```
public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
  if (goal < 0 || big < 0 || small < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  } else if (goal > big * 5 + small) {
    return false;
  } else if (goal % 5 <= small) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

is sufficient. This can be simplified to:

```
public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
  if (goal < 0 || big < 0 || small < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  } else {
    return goal <= big * 5 + small && goal % 5 <= small;
  }
}
```

Of course, the sanity check on negative goal, small or big is not strictly required but recommended. Without those checks, the result can simply be obtained by:

```
public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
  return goal <= big * 5 + small && goal % 5 <= small;
}
```

Comment: I don't think so - for example, your logic would produce true for makeBricks(0, 5, 4), where you can't actually make a four-inch goal line using only a five-inch brick.

Comment: Um, no it wouldn't. Is goal <= big * 5 + small? Yes. But goal % 5 is 4. Small is 0 so it returns false. Please try it before incorrectly stating it's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The second test is entirely unnecessary.  The first one checks to see that you have enough total length, and all is good.

But the second one *again* checks if you have enough total length (return goal / 5 <= big;) but this ignores the length added by small bricks.  The issue is you are checking if it is a multiple of 5, and automatically assuming that you are going to use only large bricks if it is.  In reality, you could use five small bricks instead. (or, as in your example, 10 small bricks.)  The last check is correct, testing if you have enough granularity to get the right length, assuming you have enough length.

Answer (score 1):

it's returning false because your second check is only comparing it to the bigs, which in your counter example you have zero of.

so 2<=0 is false.

here's a good way to do it:

```
return (Math.min(goal/5,big)*5 + small) >= goal;
```

This way you're sure to use only as many large bricks as you need, but no more, guaranteeing that the only way to reach the goal is if you have enough small bricks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried some other scenarios: "makeBricks(8, 1, 13)" "makeBricks(1, 2, 6)" where either you have not enough or too many big bricks, but you need some.  To account for both possibilities You would need something like:

```
public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
  /* Not enough bricks to make the goal so don't bother */
  if (goal > small + big * 5)
     return false;

  /* How many big bricks can we use */
  int bigBricksToUse = Math.min(big, (goal / 5) );

  /* If we use that many bigs, do we have enough small */
  return goal - (bigBricksToUse * 5) <= small;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer.

```
private static boolean makeBricks (int small, int big, int goal) {

    return ((big * 5 + small) >= goal) && (goal % big <= small);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question?

Comment: This solution fails when there are more big bricks than needed, and also has a `/ by zero` exception for `makeBricks(20, 0, 19)`

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean makeBricks (int small, int big, int goal) {
    return !(big*5 + small < goal || small < goal%5);
}
```

Uses only boolean operators to check for the absence of both failure cases `!(fail || fail)`. The obvious, not enough bricks to make the goal `big*5 + small < goal`. The less obvious, not enough small bricks when goal is not an even multiple of 5 `small < goal%5`.

Answer (score 0):

public class Bricks {

```
public boolean checkMethod(int small, int big, int goal) {
    if (goal <= small + big * 5 && goal >= big * 5) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Bricks brick = new Bricks();
    System.out.println(brick.checkMethod(10, 0, 10));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean  makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) 
{
    if (goal < 0 || big < 0 || small < 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(); 
    }
    else return goal - (5 * big + small) <= 0;
}
```

This is it. That's how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the perfect solution:

```
public static boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {

    int totalInches = small + big*5;
    if(totalInches < goal){
        return false;
    }

    int bigInches= big*5;
    int smallRequired = goal %5;

    if(smallRequired > small && bigInches != goal){
        return false;
    }else if(smallRequired <=small){
        if( bigInches >= goal || smallRequired + bigInches == goal || small +bigInches ==goal 
                || small+ bigInches == goal){
            return true;
        }if(bigInches + small > goal){
            if(small > goal-bigInches){
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably no perfect solution, but perhaps a bit more understandable than the previous ones:

```
public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
    //not testing for invalid input - no invalid input from codingbat.com (in this case)

    int obviousDemandSmall = goal%5;
    if (obviousDemandSmall>small) return false;

    boolean needSmallToMakeUpForBig = (goal/5>big) ? true : false;
    if (!needSmallToMakeUpForBig) return true;

    int superfluousSmallFromFirstGlance = small-obviousDemandSmall;
    int extraSmallCanMakeThisManyBig = superfluousSmallFromFirstGlance/5;
    int missingBig = goal/5-big;
    if (extraSmallCanMakeThisManyBig>=missingBig) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (goal < 0 || big < 0 || small < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } else {
            int reqBig = goal / 5;
            int reqSamll = goal % 5;

            if (reqBig <= big && reqSamll <= small)
                return true;
            else if (reqBig > big) {
                int remainingLen = goal - (big * 5);
                if (remainingLen <= small)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            } else
                return false;
        }
```

Comment: Perfect solution without any looping. It give me the successful solution in all my test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this:

```
public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
return goal - big * 5 <= small
        && goal % 5 <= small;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite short and easy solution I've used when solving codingbat issue:

```
public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {

// first we check if we have enough bricks to reach the goal

 if ((small + big * 5) >= goal) {

  //if yes then we check if the goal can be achieved by building it with our big bricks and how much small bricks should be needed then.

   if (goal % 5 <= small) {

    return true;

    }
  }

 return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean makeBricks(int small, int big, int goal) {
  if ((goal % 5) <= small && ((Math.floor(goal/5)) <= big || (5*big + small) >= goal))
     return true;
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```java
function makeBricks(small, big, goal){
    return (small * 1) + (big * 5) >= goal;
}
```